# Need some help about the WebRTC protocol, specifically on peer connections

Tags: webrtc, one-to-many, broadcast

I have a WebRTC app, who work like this:

- A person create a room with id
- Peers connect to the room

Currently, each peer (also the session's host) share his stream to others.

But I'd like that the host share his stream to server, without sharing directly to peers.

Comment: You'll want something like a [Kurento media server](http://www.kurento.org) as middleman then.

Comment: I just found a paid service (https://www.wowza.com/products/capabilities/webrtc-streaming-software) that can do what I want. Any idea if an open-source service alternative existe? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Then what you need is not actually WebRTC, which is a peer-to-peer solution, but a streaming server.

Comment: That streaming server would presumably still work using WebRTC, unless you want to use a completely different technology like Flash.

Comment: Thanks Adrian.

I heard for a MCU topology ... isn't it a WebRTC way to do that? (https://thenewdialtone.com/the-end-of-transcoding-webrtc-video-sessions/)